# Twisted earphones-wires

Tags: everyday-life

Just the other day I kept aside my earphones after listening to music for a long time, only to find it get twisted, well and good!

This happens every time. I feel it is a really strange phenomenon - seems like it happens on its own. How do the wires get tangled up so well? Is there any connection with the property of the material of the wire?

Comment: This can't be answered w/o a lot more info: do you move or turn around while listening?  Are the wires completely "limp" or do they have some built-in coil form?  Otherwise, it's just entropy: there's dozens of ways to tangle a wire (knot theory) and only one way to keep it straight.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1257/2451

Comment: Probably goes to how the wire has been kept, and many elastic property. Just so you mention, I was experimenting with mine. And in 7/10 random **slow** throw they have overlapping. Hence, you keep on doing it more tangled it get. One time they actually made a knot , for heavens I have been thinking just how.