# Why can I unfasten the random knots of my earphones by vibration up and down?

Tags: classical-mechanics, randomness

Very often I just put my earphones in my pocket carelessly when I walk to my school from my home.  The next time I want to use it which always has so much stochastic and fasten knots tightly. But don't worry about that, I take one end of it and vibrate up and down at constant speed and finally, it will be unfastened naturally. But why? So What's the physics behind this phenomena?

Comment: Related : [Why do earphone wires always get tangled up in pocket?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1257)

Answer (score 0):

The act of tying an actual knot is pretty sophisticated and unlikely to come about by the chaotic act of shoving your earphones in your pocket. What you perceive as knots are usually just the wires twisting together in the chaotic system. Some of these are strengthened by tension, while others are relieved by tension. Vibrating one end up and down alternately increases and decreases tension, covering both cases.

This trick doesn't always work, though. The extension cord I use for my lawnmower drives me crazy. No matter how neatly I try to roll it up for storage, it gets these knots that I can't get rid of without manually feeding the cord through the loops. I suppose it's a matter of the extension cord having greater friction than earphone cables and greater resistance to bending (and also I would have to be 75 feet tall to dangle it).

Comment: I think this isn't true. Check out this classic paper http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0166218X8990005X . They show that the probably of a random walk being unknotted goes to zero exponentially fast in the number of steps. Also, experience shows that actual knots, usually trefoils and figure eight knots, happen all the time in cords.